# Angular 4 Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance

Tags: angular, typescript

I get the folowing error provided in screenshot. I am creating a LOGIN form in Angular 4.

[image]

Here is the current code with the error.

**app.module.ts**

```
 import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { ProductComponent } from './product/product.component';
    import { MembersComponent } from './members/members.component';
    import { SortPipe } from './app.sortpipe';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
      SortPipe,
        AppComponent,
        ProductComponent,
        MembersComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule
     ],
      providers: [],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

**HTML**

```
<form class="container" [formGroup]="myGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myGroup.value)">
<input type="text" name="firstName" placeholder="firstName" formControlName="firstName"/>
<br/><br/>
<input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="lastName" formControlName="lastName"/>
<br/><br/>
<select name="gender" formControlName="gender">
<option value="female">female</option>
<option value="male">male</option>
</select>
<br/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<br/><br/><br/>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  onSubmit= function (user){
  console.log("user",user);
  }


  myGroup ;

  ngOnInIt(){
   this.myGroup = new FormGroup({

  firstName : new FormControl("umair"),
 lastName : new FormControl(""),
  gender  : new FormControl(""),
  })

  }


}
```

Any help/pointing me in the right direction would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Please consider transcribing the error in more detail in the body of the question rather than leaving it up to the answerer to open your screenshot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a typo in your `ngOnInIt`. It should be `ngOnInit`. Because of the typo, the method is not run when the component initializes and thus `myGroup` is undefined.

To avoid this kind of error you should always have your component implement the corresponding interfaces from angular. This example is exactly why they're there :)

In your example it would be:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class AppComponent implements OnInit { ... }
```

This way you will get a *compile-time* error telling you that `AppComponent` is not implementing `OnInit` if you've misspelled or forgotten it.